# Error creating bean with name 'bindingService' - Eureka & Bus AMQP

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-amqp, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-stream, beancreationexception

I'm trying to integrate Hystrix into my current spring-cloud & Netflix OSS microservice project.

I have a fresh Spring Boot version 1.4.0.RELEASE project with two dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

On project startup I receive this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bindingService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/ChannelBindingServiceConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.ChannelBindingService]: Factory method 'bindingService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validator
```

This exception only occurs when both the Eureka & Bus AMQP dependencies are together.

There is no configuration set in application or bootstrap .yml/.properties.

The only Java class present is the one generated by Spring Boot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DummyProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DummyProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Full POM:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.dummy</groupId>
        <artifactId>dummy_project</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <name>dummy_project</name>
        <description>dummy_project</description>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>Brixton.SR4</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Full Stack Trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bindingService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/ChannelBindingServiceConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.ChannelBindingService]: Factory method 'bindingService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validator
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at com.dummy.DummyProjectApplication.main(DummyProjectApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.ChannelBindingService]: Factory method 'bindingService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validator
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validator
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.ChannelBindingService.<init>(ChannelBindingService.java:71) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.ChannelBindingServiceConfiguration.bindingService(ChannelBindingServiceConfiguration.java:105) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.ChannelBindingServiceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dcfa32f2.CGLIB$bindingService$1(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.ChannelBindingServiceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dcfa32f2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$641fb65d.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.ChannelBindingServiceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dcfa32f2.bindingService(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.Validator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    ... 43 common frames omitted

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validator` should be a clue. That class is not included in the two (rather odd looking) dependencies. We could sit and discuss whether it should be included, or you could just include it yourself (e.g. via `spring-boot-starter-web`, which is the usual source, or `spring-boot-starter-validation` if you don't need web stuff).

Comment: The project was used to determine which dependencies were causing the exception. Adding the spring-boot-starter-web did resolve the issue. I was under the impression that Validator would be included in the spring-boot-starter-parent. My mistake. Interesting why this exception would only be caused when both dependencies were together.